# Angular2 Script 1014: Invalid Character

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to call a JSON object. I can get it to work if I use JSON.stringify(data), but when I switch to JSON.parse(data), then I get an error. First, here is the console errors I am getting:

```
 EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Invalid character
   EXCEPTION: SyntaxError: Invalid character
   STACKTRACE:
   SyntaxError: Invalid character
   at Anonymous function (eval code:20:42)
   at SafeSubscriber.prototype.__tryOrUnsub (eval code:225:13)
   at SafeSubscriber.prototype.next (eval code:174:17)
   at Subscriber.prototype._next (eval code:124:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:88:13)
   at MapSubscriber.prototype._next (eval code:82:9)
   at Subscriber.prototype.next (eval code:88:13)
   at onLoad (eval code:48:21)
   at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:354:18)
   at onInvokeTask (eval code:36:25)

SCRIPT1014: Invalid character
File: Subscriber.js, Line: 229, Column: 13
```

And here is my http-json.service.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http'; 

//next lines are supposed to help...
import 'rxjs/Rx';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'; //not sure if needed. for .map below
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class HTTPJsonService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }
    private jsonUrl = 'http://localhost:57470/escoapi/ActiveOffersByZip/offer-zip/';

    getEscos(zipCode: string) {

        this.jsonUrl += zipCode;
        console.log(this.jsonUrl);

        //THIS NEXT LINE IS WHERE IT STOPS. SEEMS TO BE CAUSING THE ERROR.
        return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
            .map(this.extractData);
    }

    private extractData(res: Response) {
        if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
            throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
        }
        let body = res.json();
        return body.data || {};
    }

}
```

I thought I had this working before, but oddly enough this is now not working. The typescript seems to compile okay. I'm not sure if possibly .map could be not working, but I thought I was importing the necessary files correctly (probably importing more than needed, actually).

Comment: Could you provide some exemple of jsonUrl?

Comment: Where do you call `JSON.parse()` or `JSON.stringify()`. How does the returned JSON look like?

Comment: `export class HTTPJsonComponent {
    getData: string;
    zipCode: string;

    constructor(private _httpService: HTTPJsonService) { }

    onTestGet() {
        
        this._httpService.getEscos(this.zipCode)
            .subscribe(
            data => this.getData = JSON.parse(data),
            error => alert(error),
            () => console.log('done')
            );
    }
}
`

Comment: The returned stringified JSON looks like a normal object to me,
`[{"SEQ":134770,"SERVICE_ZONE":"NGRID in Zone F"...`

etc

Answer (score 1):

Try this way , First make an Interface Body

```
export interface IBody{
     body:string;
}
```

you can add as many field you want.
and import that interface  into the service class

```
  import {IBody} from 'your_path'
  getEscos(zipCode: string):Observable<IBody[]> {

    this.jsonUrl += zipCode;
    console.log(this.jsonUrl);

    //THIS NEXT LINE IS WHERE IT STOPS. SEEMS TO BE CAUSING THE ERROR.
    return this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
           .map((res: Response) => {
              if (res.status < 200 || res.status >= 300) {
                 throw new Error('Bad response status: ' + res.status);
              }
              else{

                 let body = res.json();
                 console.log(body.data);
                 return body.data || {};
              }
    });
}
```

In this way ,interface will help you to point out if there is any problem with the data or not :) . Hope it clarifies